# In ADFS reset password should not allow last 12 passwords. How to implement?

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, adfs

I want to update password policy in an existing application. `ADFS` is used in it and I am new to `ADFS`.

> Requirement is 'User should not use his last 12 passwords.'

I want to check users top 12 passwords before setting new password or Is there any other options?

How to implement, what service/operation I need to use?

Answer (score 1):

ADFS only handles federation.

It sits on top of AD.

This is done by setting the AD [password policy](https://specopssoft.com/blog/create-fine-grained-password-policy-active-directory/).

Comment: Thank you so much @nzpcmad. Relying party trust is used in the application. Can I get How many times user used current password? and whether is the password is in last 12 passwords?

Comment: No - but if the new password is in the last 12 passwords, it won't be accepted. Also be aware that you can only change your password once a day.